# Configuring SSL with tomcat 8.5 using .keystore file - Cannot store non-Private keys

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a file tomcat (2).keystore file which I have placed in `/opt/tomcat/conf` directory. The directory permissions are set as below:

```
root@xxxxxxxxxx:/opt/tomcat# ls -l
total 112
drwxr-x--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Sep 10 03:04 bin
drwxr-x--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Sep 28 05:12 conf
drwxr-x--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Sep 10 03:04 lib
-rw-r----- 1 root   tomcat 57092 Aug  2 21:36 LICENSE
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep 28 05:15 logs
-rw-r----- 1 root   tomcat  1723 Aug  2 21:36 NOTICE
-rw-r----- 1 root   tomcat  7064 Aug  2 21:36 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r----- 1 root   tomcat 15946 Aug  2 21:36 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep 28 05:15 temp
drwxr-x--- 8 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep 28 03:52 webapps
drwxr-x--- 3 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep 10 03:19 work
```

And the `server.xml` has the following connector:

```
<Connector 
    port="8080" 
    maxThreads="1000"

    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    emptySessionPath="true"
    connectionTimeout="20000"  
    minSpareThreads="20"  
    acceptCount="100" 
    disableUploadTimeout="true" 
    enableLookups="false" 
    tcpNoDelay="true"

    scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat (2).keystore" 
    keystorePass="xxxxxx"
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    maxPostSize="97589953"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

I have also commented out the following:

`<!-- <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->`

However, I keep getting the following error in `catalina.out`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:258)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:117)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:226)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112)
        ... 20 more
```

Can someone help please? Is there any other thing I need to remove from the `server.xml`?

EDIT:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

root, Dec 19, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxx
tomcat, Dec 19, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxx
intermed, Dec 19, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxxx
```

I get the above when I run `./keytool -list -keystore "/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat (2).keystore"`

Comment: Is your keystore file read-only by any chance? It's news to me that Tomcat tries to write into it, and I don't know why it would, but it is calling `setKeyEntry()` for some reason.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it is read-only... Should I increase permission?

Comment: I think you should try making it read-write, but I have no idea why.

Comment: @EJP Now my permissions on the .keystore file looks like `-r--rw---- 1 ubuntu tomcat   7492 Sep 28 03:58 tomcat (2).keystore` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: So it isn't finding it at all. Check that you have the filename exactly correct, and the password.

Comment: @EJP The filename and password is correct. Do I need to run any keytool commands after copying the .keystore file to the server before editing `server.xml`? All I did was just copy the `tomcat (2).keystore` from one server to another, set the permissions and add the `<connectore />` to `server.xml` file. Did I miss any step?

Comment: It seems OK, as long as you follow the steps in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), whichever version is appropriate, and avoid third-party websites like the plague, as there is a lot of misinformation out there. I'm wondering about the actual filename, whether it is getting through all the XML reading etc. Can you rename it removing the `(2)` part and the spaces? There is also some confusion in your two XML extracts between `(1)` and `(2)`: does that need resolving?

Comment: Yeah tried removing it as well. I think at this point in time only options is to try and start from scratch and reinstall everything. Thanks for the link and the effort to help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out the issue. As the Exception suggests, there's some issue with the `tomcat (2).keystore` itself. So I checked the certificates in the keystore with `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -keystore tomcat (2).keystore` output of which is:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

```
root, Dec 19, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxx
tomcat, Dec 19, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxx
intermed, Dec 19, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxxx
```

Since the exception suggests that any key other than private keys are offending, I removed the `trustedCertEntry` using:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -delete -noprompt -alias intermed -keystore tomcat\ \(2\).keystore -storepass xxxxxx
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -delete -noprompt -alias root -keystore tomcat\ \(2\).keystore -storepass xxxxx
```

and restarted tomcat. This resolved the issue. Thanks @Gautam and @EJP for assistance.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that root keys you just deleted are the ones that you received from your CA . You need those.

Answer (score 5):

It's bit late, but I encountered the similar issue after migrating to tomcat 8.5.20. After some more research, I figured out a separate, reasonable solution. Many cases, certificates are not in our hand in production environment, and it is not advisable to tamper with it.
Actually looking at the implementation, it looks like tomcat tries to use first key mentioned in the key storefile, unless we provide key alias. So, in this case, if we provide key alias name in the connector, it will work just fine.

{  keyAlias="tomcat" }

Comment: That did the trick for me. Thanks! For embedded tomcat configuration with spring boot: server.ssl.key-alias=ALIAS

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're trying to setup SSL support on server. If so, your keystore should only contain your private certificates. Looks like there are some third party public keys in there or you are using JKS keystore with symmetric keys. Best bet to find out is to check the contents of your keystore. Use command

```
keytool -list -keystore yourkeystorefilename
```

And see what is in there.

Comment: Added the result of the command as an edit. Does it ring any bells? There are no public keys.

Comment: I believe `tomcat, Dec 19, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xxxx` is your server's private key. What are the other two showing up as trusted certificates? Why do you need them in this keystore. If those are for third party endpoints that you wish to invoke from your application, add those certificates to `cacerts`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer and provide steps/references?

Comment: Having trusted certificates in a keystore does not cause this error. Presumably they are the CA root certificate and its chain.

Comment: That's a theory based on the error. As per stacktrace, Tomcat seems to be writing to the keystore which is weird in itself. I could say that is the problem, and guess that is what you're thinking too. Again just a theory.

Comment: Looks like @EJP is right, this isn't about public keys in keystore. Did it work on setting keystore to rw? Looks like tomcat is not able to get to the keystore and finding keystore as null. Refer JSSEUtil source code at https://apache.googlesource.com/tomcat/+/refs/heads/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSEUtil.java , if keystore is null it tries to create an in memory keystore and write keys to it. That's where `setKeyEntry` is getting invoked

Comment: Why does it find as `null`?

Comment: I don't know what 'theory based on the error' is supposed to mean, but anything posted here that *isn't* 'based on the error' is by definition irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP you're right... cheers.... Anyway, the bottomline is that his Tomcat is unable to find the keystore at all. Even setting permissions didn't work. So if I may ask, check once what user are you running tomcat with. By any chance you forget to sudo to tomcat before starting tomcat. Another weird thing is port 8080 for https, in the configurations. Is http port changed to something else or is it also 8080? Again may not exactly be the reason but who knows, weird things happen.

Comment: @Gautam I start tomcat with `sudo systemctl restart tomcat` ... Permission to the keystore file is as `-r--rw---- 1 root tomcat 7492 Sep 28 03:58 tomcat.keystore`. I even tried changing the name of the keystore from `tomcat (2).keystore` to `tomcat.keystore`... Thanks for help so far. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is systemctl part of tomcat group? Just do an `id systemctl`.

Comment: `id: ‘systemctl’: no such user`

Comment: Damn... didn't realize it was `systemctl`. :(. Sorry for that, I was on phone when I wrote that.  I haven't used `systemd` services, so I do not know much of that. Can you check what user and group is tomcat using, I guess `top` should be able to tell you that.

Comment: I don't think it should cause a problem. It just let me start tomcat as a service. User for tomcat is 'tomcat'. My installation is a standard tomcat installation